# Is WonderShare's video editor a viable alternative to Camtasia Studio?

Tags: video-editor

I wanted to experiment with creating YouTube video's, but Windows Movie Maker or Apple iMovie just don't cut it. Camtasia Studio looks like something that much more suits my needs, but is a little too pricy at this stage.

I found Wondershare's video editor, which has a more acceptable price, but was unsure whether it is good enough quality at a comparable level to Camtasia Studio (Windows).

I need:

1. An easy-to-use, time-saving interface
2. Switching, embedding and manipulating content like videos, images, texts.
3. Transitional effects.
4. Captions.
5. High quality screen capture.

Comment: I have not used it, but I would expect that Wondershare's product is rather poor.  They appear to be a cheap knock off brand that spends more of their time paying for fake reviews and spamming forums than they do with software development.  I'd recommend staying away.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for software for windows then:

.Lightworks (free but you need an account)

.Jahashaka

.If you do not want to use either of those, use Windows Live, Blender, slowmoVideo, and GoPro Studio together in your workflow.
  Typically what I do is import the file using GoPro studio(which can be used on most video formats) and color correct the video, then either using GoPro studio or slowmoVideo I add slow motion effects if needed, and Blender can be use to add CG (something I've never done) or maybe camera movement. The final edit of clips, i.e syncing it to music, etc. is done in Windows Live Movie Maker.

If you are uploading to YouTube I highly recomend you check out GoPro studio.

Comment: Jahshaka is pretty much dead in the water at the moment. KDEnlive is probably the most active project at the moment but there's also kino, lumiera, LiVES and of course Blender.

Comment: Yeah but if he doesn't have Linux he can't use kden live.....that being said if he does have Linux good for him because kdenlive is pretty darn powerful....

Comment: kdenlive is also available for mac, but not for windows at the moment.